# How can I clean up my Dendrogram i.e. improve it's aesthetics? (R Code provided)

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

Hi Guys I have a data on which I need to do hierarchical clustering. However my Dendrogram is very messy (since its 583 observations). Since I need to divide this Dendrogram into clusters (which I know how to), I was wondering what I could do to make it look cleaner/neater (and how). I have provided my code below, along with the plot to give some context.

```
##For All 583 Observations
idx_583 <- sample(1:nrow(ilpd_df), 583)
distance_matrix <- dist(as.matrix(ilpd_df[idx_583,-c(1,2,10,11)]), 
                        method = "euclidean") #Creates Hierarchical Clustering Solution

hc <- hclust(distance_matrix, method = "average")
plot(hc, hang = -1, labels=ilpd_df$Class)
```

[image]

Comment: Also look at this tutorial for things you can do with dendrograms: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the factoextra package, it provides prettier plot functions for dendrograms. Also, you can remove the the text at the bottom with sub=F and labels=F.